# How to make paths to leafs of a JSON?

Tags: json, path, jq

Say we have the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "dir-1": [
      "file-1.1",
      "file-1.2"
    ]
  },
  "dir-1",
  {
    "dir-2": [
      "file-2.1"
    ]
  }
]
```

And we want to get the next output:

```
  "dir-1/file-1.1"
  "dir-1/file-1.2"
  "dir-1"
  "dir-2/file-2.1"
```

i.e. to get the paths to all leafs, joining items with `/`. Is there a way to do that on JQ?

I tried something like this:

```
cat source-file | jq 'path(..) | [ .[] | tostring ] | join("/")'
```

But it doesn't produce what I need even close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take advantage of how streams work by merging the path with their values. Streams will only emit `path, value` pairs for leaf values.  Just ignore the numbered indices.

```
$ jq --stream '
select(length == 2) | [(.[0][] | select(strings)), .[1]] | join("/")
' source-file
```

returns:

```
"dir-1/file-1.1"
"dir-1/file-1.2"
"dir-1"
"dir-2/file-2.1"
```

Comment: You're genius! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution similar to [Jeff Mercado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47005033/8379597)'s which uses `tostream` and `flatten`

```
tostream | select(length==2) | .[0] |= map(strings) | flatten | join("/")
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/mrq5-WqKip)

Another way is to use a recursive function to walk the input such as

```
def slashpaths($p):
  def concat($p;$k): if $p=="" then $k else "\($p)/\($k)" end;
  if   type=="array"  then .[] | slashpaths($p)
  elif type=="object" then
       keys_unsorted[] as $k
     | .[$k] | slashpaths(concat($p;$k))
  else concat($p;.) end;
slashpaths("")
```

[Try it online at tio.run!](https://tio.run/##XY/RToQwEEXf/YrJpA@SUAw8stkvQWIqDIGlaWtbYojsr4ujsKI7D02nc8/c28vbWn1gO3iZY1lhN2iSeZZjersWWF/TXZBuyuJXWbCyvtbLClwtdRC0Cr1TsQ@PwiXlA8Bt0ljTqMivJzEmJQwdCHc@I0LsyYAYgXQgwOdv7onPMUEg0572FawHiLMjZpT3akbYyKyqYbnz3RnSTO2Mfb1QEze3ffxTI83hZTLB@kgtr1KBsxyChfeL8c7h31cOM45/TLLkSP8HRUzW9dO6OFgTVinNpLUcjJsiN169SztFbr4A)

Comment: What is the performance of the recursive function?  Part of the reason I included it was becuase I thought the bottom-up construction `tostream` does could be prohibitive.

Comment: The solution using `tostream` is much slower than any of the others (i.e. the one using `--stream`, the recursive walk-like one, or the straightforward one based on `paths`). This is because `tostream` incurs BOTH the cost of reading in the entire file and the cost of streaming the contents.  For a large file, the u+s times were respectively: `tostream`: 38s, `slashpaths`: 10.4, `--stream`: 15.5s, `paths`: 22.4s.

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown.  This is good to know.  `tostream` is often very convenient but it can also be inefficient I think in part because of the number of intermediate objects it creates.  Each path it returns starts at the leaf [`[[],$dot]`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L236) and every interior key prepends to [`.[0]`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L246).  If many of those paths are subsequently discarded (which is often if they are filtered or aggregated) that's a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--stream` is good but the following is perhaps less esoteric:

```
paths(scalars) as $p
| getpath($p) as $v
| ($p | map(strings) + [$v])
| join("/")
```

(If using jq 1.4 or earlier, and if any of the leaves might be numeric or boolean or null, then `[$v]` above should be replaced by `[$v|tostring]`.)

Whether the result should be regarded as "paths to leaves" is another matter...